# Oracle SQL: Retrieving data for multiple weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to query data over multiple weeks into columns.

```
SELECT
    MAR.AR,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN MAR.CREATION_DAY >= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-28
                    AND MAR.CREATION_DAY <= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [WEEK_N-3]
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN MAR.CREATION_DAY >= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-21
                    AND MAR.CREATION_DAY <= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [WEEK_N-2]
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN MAR.CREATION_DAY >= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-14
                    AND MAR.CREATION_DAY <= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [WEEK_N-1]
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN MAR.CREATION_DAY >= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-7
                    AND MAR.CREATION_DAY <= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS [WEEK_N]
FROM
    TABLE_DATA MAR
WHERE
    MAR.CREATION_DAY >= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')-28
    AND MAR.CREATION_DAY <= TO_DATE({RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}, 'YYYYMMDD')
GROUP BY
    MAR.AR
```

The SQL errors out as I'm using {RUN_Date_YYYYMMDD}. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `{RUN_Date_YYYYMMDD}` supposed to mean?

Comment: It returns the date I select in my application. I usually choose a Saturday.
I don't want to hardcode the date in the query.

Comment: What is the text of the query as passed to Oracle?

Comment: Hi Mat,
Thank you for your time. It was a lame mistake from my side. I didn't stick the variable in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use

```
'{RUN_Date_YYYYMMDD}'
```

instead of

```
{RUN_Date_YYYYMMDD}
```